# Standardized Coefficient (beta)

Tags: regression-coefficients

I am doing research on advanced manufacturing technologies such as Computer Aided Design, Computer Numerical Machines and Computer Aided Engineering.

When I found their Standardized Coefficient (beta) values some have negative values.

Can we ignore the minus sign from the value of Standardized Coefficient (beta)?

For example, the value of Beta is -0.58: can I ignore sign "-"?

What does the negative value of Standardized Coefficient (beta) show?

Comment: Standardized coefficients are positive, zero or negative depending on whether the corresponding regression coefficients are positive, zero or negative.  That follows from their definition. I wouldn't ignore the sign unless you have no interest in the direction of the relationship.

Comment: Welcome to our site!